# Javascript: quick script to line up pipe-delimited text (or any-character-delimited text)

Tags: javascript, string, csv

**Background:** I've written this before but I don't like the approach. The reason is because Javascript does not have "sprintf" and that is something I use heavily if the language supports it.

**Question:** How would you use javascript to go from BEFORE to AFTER? If anyone has a solution with very small number of lines of code, or something from a javascript string library, that would be informative. TIA.

BEFORE:

```
red| lightblue| green 
cherry| ice| mint 
round| cubic| flowery
```

AFTER:

```
red    | lightblue | green 
cherry | ice       | mint 
round  | cubic     | flowery
```

**Disclaimer:** This is not homework or any such thing, just looking for new ideas. Also, this is not browser-based javascript. This is not a web-development question, but a javascript programming question.

Comment: Why would you want javascript to do this? HTML is intended for showing the markup.

Comment: Well, it could be used in a Windows Scripting Host context, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like `sprintf`, why not look for a [JavaScript implementation](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=javascript+sprintf+implementation&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) for it?

Comment: Careful, the first hit there's implementation doesn't support padding values.

Answer (score 1):

```
function pad(str, len) {
    for (var count = len - str.length; count > 0; count--) {
        str = str + " ";
    }
    return str;
}

console.log(pad("red", 7) + "| " + pad("lightblue", 9) + "| " + pad("green", 7));
//etc.
```

Yeah, concatenating characters one by one is inefficient, but generally you'll only have a small number of iterations.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what i was trying to avoid. Just wondering if there is an alternate approach i haven't thought of ... regex tricks or something ...

Comment: Well, I suppose there are other fun ways of doing it. Like if you know the maximum length, you could do something like `return str + "         ".substr(str.length)` (to always pad it to 9) but other than that... I got nothin'. :)

Comment: Argh, stupid HTML. Assume the `" "` above has nine spaces in it.